# Networking problems disappear when a switch is connected to gateway via another switch

Tags: networking, internet, lan, switch, fortigate

I have a strange problem, and I wonder if anyone can give me insights on its root-cause.

If my switches and firewall/gateway are in the following configuration:
[image: Fortigate and switches in problematic configuration]
Then the machines connected to the Aruba switch behaves strangely: most cannot even ping to the Internet, and those who can, give horrendously response times - and would lose the Internet connectivity after a few seconds.

However, if I connect the Aruba switch via the D-Link switch:
[image: No problem configuration]
Then all works fine, and I see no networking problems.

Is there an explanation for the different networking behaviours?
In both configurations we're dealing with MAC addresses, and I don't see why connecting via another switch should change the networking behaviour.

Comment: Where the diagrams say, "To LAN", what is the LAN? More switches? Are you sure you're not making a network loop?

Comment: Also, have you ruled out a faulty cable, port speed negotiation issues and incorrectly setup vlans ?

Comment: "To LAN" is connecting directly to small switches to which machines connect directly, or directly to the machines.
If there were network loops, wouldn't they still be there in the second (no problem) configuration? @spiff

Comment: The two switches were working correctly without any configuration changes for the last 7 months. I ruled out cable problems. @davidgo

Comment: @boardrider I suppose it could depend on how you have STP set up. If you have STP enabled on some ports of some boxes but disabled on others, you could have topologies where STP is unable to detect and break the loop. Running tcpdump or Wireshark or any sniffer of your choosing should show if you have loops, as it's most likely broadcast/multicast traffic that's getting looped. So you shouldn't even have to use promiscuous mode or port mirroring to see the storm of multicasts and broadcasts.

Comment: By default, Aruba switched come with STP disabled, and I did not enable it there. I guess I should look into enabling STP on our Aruba switches. @Spiff